# Libgdx Gwt compile error with tween engine

Tags: java, gwt, gradle, libgdx, tween

[ERROR] Unable to find 'aurelienribon/tweenengine.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?

i followed every step in the libgdx wiki on how to install universal tween engine and it keeps giving me this error.

I have no idea what this aurelienribon.tweenengine.gwt.xml is since i cannot find it anywhere on my pc and i dont understand what i can do to fix it.

this is the guide i followed:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Universal-Tween-Engine

and i saw someone with the same problem on here who apparently fixed it but i could not deduct how exactly he did it from the details he gave.

thanks in advance.

Comment: have u added `tweenengine` jar in path?

Comment: i have tried several approaches including adding the jar to the path and export order but to no avail. Then i went online and looked at the guide on the libgdx wiki and followed it to the T. Mind you this worked fine for everything else except the html project. which keeps giving me the same error no matter what i try.

Comment: ugh... just figured it out. Thanks a bunch going to post as answer in case someone else has the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason why it wasnt working was because i only had the tween-engine-api.jar in the libs folder created in the guide at:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Universal-Tween-Engine

it in fact needed to have the source jar as well which i did not have because i rarely use them. Turns out gwt needs them in order to compile.

so just to clarify, libs folder must have both tween-engine.api.jar and tween-engine-api-source.jar.